# How to use enumerate in this program?

Tags: file, record, enumerate

```
f=open('Student.dat','r+') # opens Student.dat file
roll1=input("Enter roll to be found") # to find a record in a list using a roll no
rec=f.readlines()
for i,lst in enumerate(rec):
        if lst == roll1:
            print rec[i]
```

Is this the proper way to use enumerate?? or should i use another loop within??

Answer (score 1):

Here `enumerate` doesn't help much; you could use instead (which would be simpler and clearer):

```
for i in rec:
    if i == roll1:
        print i
```

`enumerate` is useful when you really need to get *at the same time* values and indices, which doesn't seem to be the case here. (In your piece of code `rec[i]` does the same thing than `lst`; thus if you really want to use `enumerate` you should replace it.)

By the way, you should add better tags to your question, at least `python`.

Comment: what i meant was: the list is: [1.,'apple',2.'mango'] if its like this, then how do you get the record (completely) that has roll no:1 using enumerate and then print it?? I tried to add python tag but it wont come.